# issues with intersect in matlab

Tags: matlab, set-intersection, julian-date

Consider the following example:

```
time = datenum('2010-03-03 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):60/(60*24):...
    datenum('2010-07-31 23:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');

Jday = datenum('2010-01-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):60/(60*24):...
    datenum('2010-12-31 23:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');

idx = intersect(time,Jday);
```

Why isn't idx the same size as time? I would have thought that these should be identical in length seeing as time is just a portion of Jday. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create vectors using the [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html), with a non-integer interval. Since `intersect` does element comparisons, you're bound to have inaccuracies due to their floating-point representation, and in this case I suspect that it's the issue. If you want to verify that, I suggest that you use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to identify which members are not equal (but supposed to be).

Comment: Thaks, I assumed the issue may have been due to the floating points.